# Throwable in log.e (String tag, String msg, Throwable tr)

Tags: android

I am reviewing android's code, saw log.e (String tag, String msg, Throwable tr) in code, but don't have any idea about 3rd parameter. 
Please explain what is the functioning of 3rd parameter(Throwable tr) ?

Comment: see try ... catch ... statement you can use that Log method in a catch clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`java.lang.Throwable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Throwable.html) is something you can `throw`, for example an `Exception`.

The stacktrace of the throwable passed in the third arg will be logged [as mentioned in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#e%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable%29).

> is it possible that log.e(tag, msg, tr) throw exception, due to invalid tr(what if tr == null?)

Code where exceptions are logged are typically in `catch` blocks where the exception is not null. There can be a NPE "println needs a message" if `msg` is `null` though.

Comment: is it possible that log.e(tag, msg, tr) throw exception, due to invalid tr(what if tr is null?)